# Doctrine - How to create inverse relation?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

In symfony I created two entities from a database already created. I used the following commands from the console of symfony:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force IDFrontendBundle xml
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities IDFrontendBundle
```

Two of the entities that generate me and where I have the problem are as follows

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ProviderRate
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="provider_rate", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_proveedor_has_producto_compra_producto_compra1_idx", columns={"product_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_id_tarifa_proveedor_id_moneda1_idx", columns={"currency_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_3A645C45A53A8AA", columns={"provider_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\ProviderRateRepository")
 */
class ProviderRate
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="reference", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 */
private $reference;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount_per_unit", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $amountPerUnit;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="unit_price", type="decimal", precision=25, scale=3, nullable=false)
 */
private $unitPrice;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="discount", type="decimal", precision=25, scale=3, nullable=false)
 */
private $discount;

/**
 * @var \IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Providers
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Providers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="provider_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $provider;

/**
 * @var \IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Products
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @var \IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Currencies
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Currencies")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="currency_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $currency;
```

and

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Products
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_producto_UNIQUE", columns={"id"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_id_productos_id_categorias1_idx", columns={"category_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_id_productos_id_producto_tipo1_idx", columns={"type"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_id_productos_id_moneda1_idx", columns={"currency_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\ProductsRepository")
 */
class Products
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description_long", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $descriptionLong;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount_per_unit", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $amountPerUnit;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="weight", type="decimal", precision=11, scale=3, nullable=false)
     */
    private $weight;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="web", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $web;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isactive;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdtime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdtime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="modifiedtime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $modifiedtime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedtime", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedtime;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isDeleted", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isdeleted;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Categories
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var \IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\ProductTypes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\ProductTypes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var \IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Currencies
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Currencies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="currency_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Sets", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_sets",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="set_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $set;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Products", mappedBy="productParentid")
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Documents", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_attachments",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $document;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Images", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_images",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $image;

 /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->set = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->product = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->document = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->image = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->providerRate = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

I tried creating a new variable to join the two tables in reverse order into the product class

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\ProviderRate", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="product_id")
 * })
 */
private $providerRate;
```

But when I make a DQL query, symfony tells me that there is no association.
Is there any way to do this?

```
$dql = "SELECT p, pr FROM IDFrontendBundle:Products p
                        JOIN p.providerRate pr";
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You relationship cardinality is different on each side.

```
ProviderRate -> Product (OneToOne)
Product -> ProviderRate (OneToMany)
```

As such, it won't work. `OneToOne` should be on both sides **or**, `OneToMany` should be paired with `ManyToOne`.

I assume the following:

- One `Product` can has multiple `ProviderRate`s. **It that correct?**

If so, you need:

<kbd>**ProviderRate class**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @var \IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Products
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Products", mappedBy="providerRate")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $product;
```

<kbd>**Products class**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\ProviderRate", inversedBy="product")
 */
private $providerRate;
```

As you can see, once you declase `@JoinColums` on either of relationshp's sides, there is no need to specify one on other side. Also, `inversedBy` should be matched by `mappedBy`.

Does this help?

**EDIT**

Change mappedBy and inversedBy attribute order.

<kbd>**ProviderRate class**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @var \IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Products
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Products", inversedBy="providerRate")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $product;
```

<kbd>**Products class**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\ProviderRate", mappedBy="product")
 */
private $providerRate;
```

Comment: Hello Jovan, thanks for your answer.

I tried what you mention me, but still giving me the same error.
This is the error message that returns me.

`Semantical Error] line 0, col 73 near 'pr': Error: Class IDavid\FrontendBundle\Entity\Products has no association named providerRate`

Comment: I tried to restart the server, but still no go. Are there entities recharge or clean any kind of caching in Symfony?

Comment: Yup, restarting server would be a last resort and it should clear the server side cache. Can you update your question with the query you tried running?

Comment: The query that I tried running is:

`$dql = "SELECT p, pr FROM IDFrontendBundle:Products p
                        JOIN p.providerRate pr";
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);`

Comment: See if you have some of those `.xml` config files left behind after generating annotation based entities.

Comment: DONE!!! I deleted the Doctrine folder inside `/resources/config` and gave me an error with the annotations, with the `inversedBy` and `mappedBy` attribute.
I changed the order of these attributes. I used `mappedBy` in `product.php` class instead of `inversedBy`. In `ProviderRate.php` class `inversedBy` instead of `mappedBy`

Thanks so much

Comment: @JovanPerovic small comment, "cardinality" instead of "carnality" ;)

Comment: Oh dear! :) Thanks a lot for spotting that one :)